# jquery click function load php-page only first click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

page is loaded only once, that is, when you press the button the first time. How to make it so that it is loaded and on subsequent pressings? And how to pass data from PHP to javascript? javascript alert works fine, but page bbb.php load only 1-st time. tnx

```
<body>

<div id="stage">STAGE</div>

<div id="driver"><p>click to load graph</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function bindClicks() {
    $("#driver").live('click', function () {

      $.get("http://127.0.0.1/bbb.php", {year: "2011", $month: "08", day: "06"}, function (data) {

        $('#stage').html(data);
        alert("work fine");

      });

    });

  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (event) {
    bindClicks();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the browser caches your request so if your url is the same, it will only return the cached content.

Just add a timestamp at the end of your url. Example:

```
var date = new Date();
$.get("http://127.0.0.1/bbb.php?_" + date.getTime(), { year: "2011", $month: "08", day: "06" }, function(data){
    $('#stage').html(data);
    alert("work fine");
});
```

Or you can also let jquery do it for you. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1/bbb.php",
  data: { year: "2011", $month: "08", day: "06" }
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    $('#stage').html(data);
    alert("work fine");
  }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I took the second example, where the inserted 

`data: {year: 2011, month: Math.floor (Math.random () * (12 - 1 + 1)) + 1, day: 06} `

and now work